# Laravel 5 Interface 'Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast' not found

Tags: php, laravel-5, redis, socket.io

Currently I am trying to setup socket.io & redis for my laravel 5 project.
I've created a event that uses Interface Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast.
But I am getting the following error :

```
Interface 'Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast' not found
```

Comment: Is there a use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast; at the top of the event page?

Comment: What minor version of Laravel are you using

Comment: Yes there is  

use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class SocketEvent extends Event implements ShouldBroadcast

Comment: It is version Version 5.0.35 @jszobody

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Laravel 5.0 does not have event broadcasting, that's why the interface can't be found. See the Event docs here from 5.0:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/events

Broadcasting was introduced in 5.1:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/events#broadcasting-events

Some reference material:

- https://laracasts.com/lessons/broadcasting-events-in-laravel-5-1
- http://www.sitepoint.com/real-time-apps-laravel-5-1-event-broadcasting/
- https://mattstauffer.co/blog/broadcasting-events-with-pusher-socket-in-laravel-5.1